# How to manage user roles in a mobile app?

Tags: flutter, hybrid-mobile-app

I need to create a flutter mobile app (medium scale), that can be used by 3 types of users for eg: Admin, Employee, Customer etc. Each user role has different capabilities. The mobile app will be integrated with the APIs.

Is it a good idea to create 2 mobile apps one for admin & employee, & the other app for the customer or just to create 1 app for all three types of user roles & manage it with role based access.

The reasons behind creating two apps for admin, employee & customer are as follows:

1. Reducing application weight or size
2. Reducing the no of updates that would go for the customer

But also I feel that creating 2 mobile apps for the 3 types of user roles have some limitations such as:

1. Difficulty in maintaining 2 apps
2. Adding new user roles will be difficult in future, we may have to create another separate app

So which is better, creating 1 app & managing it by role based access or creating 2 different apps for the 3 types of user roles?

Appreciate your support!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You really should create two apps. Having admin and employee functionality in a public application is a huge security risk.

You just need to make a mistake with permissions once and one of your customers can wreak havoc.

I would suggest making your Admin app a progressive web app which can still be installed like a native app, but you have the benefit of it updating automatically. And you wouldn't even need to publish it to an app store, which makes it a breeze to push changes to.

Comment: But here I don't want to show the sign up view for the employee. I only want to show the sign up view to the admin. So that the admin can go and add the employee, with some default login credentials. Later, the employee can go and reset his password via the login view. But I don't want him (employee) to access the sign up view. Because, if he accesses the sign up view, again the employee will also get admin privileges. How can I handle this?

Comment: Use two different apps.